# Codeigniter 3 Select all from table but exclude the current group id

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Got a question.
Currently working on a multiselect for a form to add users to a group, but when the user is allready in the current group i dont whant it to show in the dropdown again.

i have tried many thing but no working solution yet.

```
$group_id = $currentgroup;

$this->db->select('users.id, users.email');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('users_groups_data','users_groups_data.user_id =     users.id','left');
$this->db->where('users_groups_data.group_id !=', $group_id);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks

Comment: This should be `$this->db->where_not_in('users_groups_data.group_id', $group_id);`

Comment: When is change it to not in i get only the list from the users that are in the  users_groups_data database

Comment: `print_r($group_id)` what r u getting?

Comment: the correct group id number

Comment: $this->db->select('users.id, users.email');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->join('users_groups_data','users_groups_data.user_id = users.id','left');
           $this->db->where_not_in('users_groups_data.group_id', $group_id);
           $query = $this->db->get();

           foreach ($query->result_array() as $tablerow) {
                      $ddmenu[$tablerow['id']] = $tablerow['email'];
           }
           $data['users'] = $ddmenu;

is what i use

Comment: Debugmode

SELECT *
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `users_groups_data` ON `users_groups_data`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users_groups_data`.`group_id` != '24'

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN users_groups_data ON users_groups_data.user_id = users.id WHERE users_groups_data.group_id != '24'` its not working? run this in php myadmin

Comment: That is not working, i get 2 wrong users and really dont know why i get that users. Only one of them is in the group with id 24

And the rest of the users not even showing up

It seems it show all the users who got a record in the users_groups_data table instead of all users from the users list en exclude the ones with the same group id

Comment: what error are u getting in php myadmin?

Comment: i dont got any error i get 2 results but that are not the correct ones

Comment: i get 2 users that are in the users_groups_data table that dont have the current group id, but i need all users from the users table that are not in de database users_groups_data table with the current id. users can have multi groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `$group_id` consist on group multiselect than you need to use `where_not_in`

```
$this->db->where_not_in('users_groups_data.group_id', $group_id);
```

Comment: i tryed with where not in but then it gives me the list from the users that are in the users_groups_data database instead.